# Google Cloud ESP advertising invalid compression formats to gRPC server

Tags: docker, nginx, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, grpc

[Cloud Endpoints: Architectural Overview](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/architecture-overview) provides a high-level view of [Cloud Endpoints Architecture](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/architecture-overview#cloud_endpoints_architecture), and thus, the architecture of my web application.

From the highest level, it's just a client-server architecture with an [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) HTTP reverse proxy server.

```
browser <----> ESP   <----------> gRPC
client  <JSON> proxy <-ProtoBuf-> server
```

The `proxy` and `server` run on the same [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/) virtual machine but in separate Docker containers connected with a [Docker bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).

The proxy trans-codes between JSON and Protocol Buffers.

When a request originates from the `proxy` to the `server`, Docker logs show:

```
 call.cc:879]  Invalid entry in accept encodingmetadata: 'deflate'. Ignoring.
 call.cc:879]  Invalid entry in accept encodingmetadata: 'br'. Ignoring.
```

From [MDN web docs for accept-encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding)

> The Accept-Encoding request HTTP header advertises which content
>   encoding, usually a compression algorithm, the client is able to
>   understand.

- `deflate`: A compression format using the zlib structure, with the deflate compression algorithm.
- `br`: A compression format using the Brotli algorithm.

From this I assume the ESP is advertising `deflate` and `br` compression formats, but both are ignored by the gRPC server. I don't recall specifying any compression methods when I built the [pulled](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) the [ESP](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/endpoints-release/GLOBAL/endpoints-runtime?gcrImageListsize=50) or built the gRPC server.

A [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Invalid%20entry%20in%20accept%20encoding%20metadata%3A%20%27br%27.%20Ignoring.%22&oq=%22Invalid%20entry%20in%20accept%20encoding%20metadata%3A%20%27br%27.%20Ignoring.%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) yielded only one related issue against a Google run public repo: [Invalid entry in accept encoding metadata](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/3999).  The problem there was a mismatch of gPRC library versions.

My gRPC server is installed with

- grpcio-1.10.1
- grpcio-tools-1.10.1
- protobuf-3.5.2.post1

The ESP is a pre-built Docker image (based on NGINX) from https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/endpoints-release/GLOBAL/endpoints-runtime. I'm using tags `1`, `1.15` or `1.15.0` (they all tag the same, latest version).

My gRPC server uses the [latest gPRC version (1.10.1)](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.10.1), so I'm unsure how there could be a mismatch here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESP advertises that "br" and "deflate" *are supported* but gRPC server does not support it, which should be fine since you are not using compression at all. gRPC mistakenly dumps this message as an error. You can file an issue for this to [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/new). Your program should still be able to run normally.